# Как получить все атрибуты текущего пользователя в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть Laravel  контроллер где я с помощью кода

```
$user = Auth::user();
```

визываю  текущего пользователя `$user`, и могу получить  его атрибуты  например

```
$user->name;
$user->surname;
```

Но как получить *массив или коллекцию* **всех атрибутов** пользователя `$user` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Auth::user()` это уже объект пользователя со всеми его свойствами. Если вы их хотите видеть в более привычном виде, то посмотрите, например так `Auth::user()->toArray()`